# Android Navigation Component fragment transitions have white background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using the Jetpack Navigation library and having an issue with the fragment transitions, either if it's a fade or slide animation it always has a white background instead of the previous screen content.

fragment A -> fragment B, when the animation is running instead of seeing the background as fragment A, it's a white background.

*navigation*

```
  <fragment
      android:id="@+id/nav_page"
      android:name="my.fragmenta"
      tools:layout="@layout/fragment_a">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_to_b"
        app:destination="@id/nav_b"
        app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_up"
        app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_down"/>
  </fragment>
```

*activity style*

```
  <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusBarColor</item>
  </style>
```

*anim files*

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

and

```
<translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Comment: Share the code of your `anim` files please.

Comment: Could you please try using `app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_down"` instead of `popExitAnim`, the latter is used when you press back button or going back in your stack

Comment: @ElJazouli Did you figure out how to solve that?

Comment: @extmkv see updated post

Answer (score 2):

After many tries I figured this is the best approach to animate transitions:

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/id"
    app:destination="@id/dest"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_bottom"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_top"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_top"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_bottom"/>
```

or

```
<action
    android:id="@+id/id"
    app:destination="@id/dest"
    app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
    app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
    app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
    app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"/>
```

you should have all four events to have a smooth animation.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part is you have to define all the **Anim** field in the action.
As you can see bellow:

```
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_profileFragment_to_personalInfoFragment"
        app:destination="@id/personalInfoFragment"
        app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:exitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"
        app:popEnterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
        app:popExitAnim="@android:anim/slide_out_right"/>
```